# Create HTML Object in JavaScript using a variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, element

```
var num;
var element = '<div><p id="number">**num**</p></div>';     
$('#example').append(element);
```

How can I display var num as text in the created html object?

Comment: Look up string concatenation (or template literals)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the `num` variable like `<div><p id="number">'+num+'</p></div>`

```js
var num = 'someNum';
var element = '<div><p id="number">'+num+'</p></div>';     
$('#example').append(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='example'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var num;
var element = `<div><p id="number">**${num}**</p></div>`;     
$('#example').append(element);
```

use template strings.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var num;

var $element = $('<div><p id="number"></p></div>');

$element.find('#number').html(num);

$('#example').append($element);
```

Comment: Errer: Uncaught Reference

Comment: Because you need to include jQuery first.

Answer (score 0):

By using concatenation

```
var num;
var element = '<div><p id="number">'+num+'</p></div>';     
$('#example').append(element);
```